# Element position issue after dropped with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two HTML div elements, one source one destiny; inside of each one there are canvas elements. I want to be able to drag and drop one of these canvases from the source div into the destiny div using jQuery UI.

The problem is that once a canvas is dropped, its new position inside the destiny div is not as expected and I have not been able to correct this.

Here is the code I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/1/

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery droppable is just working fine. `drop` event handler is able to append the canvas to the `destiny`. Since, the draggable adds some styles to the canvas, canvas looks like its going outside of the `destiny` div.

Here, one way to solve this quick & easy.

```
$("#destiny").droppable({
    accept: "#source > canvas",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to append the draggable canvas using the callback function of the droppable method. This wasn't necessary as the drop then already happens.

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/Mf6zJ/2/

**Source**: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Hope this solves your problem